# get the biggest id value of sibling

Tags: jquery

Below code console.log will get `[<div class="a" id="0">0</div>, <div class="a" id="1">1</div>, ..]`
How to know sibling div `.a`'s id value get the biggest number?

```
$('.a').hover(function(){
    console.log('$('.a')');
},function(){});
```

html

```
<div class="a" id="0">0</div>
<div class="a" id="1">1</div>
<div class="a" id="2">2</div>
<div class="a" id="3">3</div>
```

Comment: unrelated, but just somehing i noticed, lose the `hover`, use the `mouseover,mouseleave`

Comment: As per the WC3, ID's should never start with, or be by themselves an integer.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy depends which part of W3C you ask.  It's legal in HTML5, but not in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a different approach and instead of `id` I used [`data-id`](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsvvk/1/)

```
// this var will store the element with the highest ID
var big;
$(".a").each(function() {
    if (!big) // if big is not set, assume the first is the highest
        big = this;
    else
    {
        // retrieves the `data-id` from the element
        // converts to integer and compare, re-assign big if needed
        if (parseInt($(this).data("id")) > parseInt($(big).data("id")))
            big = this;
    }
});

// displays the `data-id` of the element with the highest value
alert($(big).data("id"));
```

html code:

```
<div class="a" data-id="0">0</div>
<div class="a" data-id="30">30</div>
<div class="a" data-id="1">1</div>
<div class="a" data-id="2">2</div>
<div class="a" data-id="3">3</div>
```

[See jQuery data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Answer (score 6):

This is the shortest code I can think of:

```
var high = Math.max.apply(null, $('.a').map(function(_, el) {
    return +el.id;
}));
```

If you wish to use `data-id` instead just replace `el.id` with `$(el).data('id')`.

Please note that this method is not "data safe" because it does not sanitise the individual values before trying to find the max value.   If you run it on the wrong elements (garbage in) you'll get the wrong answer (garbage out).  Don't do that.  ;-)

Comment: Note 1) that this return the id, not the element which seems to be op goal 2) it fails as soon as one of the element has no id or has a non numerical id.

Comment: That's sad : `Math.max.apply(null, [1,2,NaN])` ==> `NaN`

Comment: @dystroy my reading is that he wants the "biggest ID".  The `NaN` issue with `Math.max` is a bit annoying, yes.

Comment: As for no-id or non-numeric - that's just a case of garbage-in-garbage-out.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should not use id starting with a number. They're correct in HTML5 but are problematic in many tools and in CSS.

But if you want to get the element with biggest id, you could do this :

```
var me;
$('.a').each(function(){
   var num = Number(this.id); // this ensures the id is only a number
   if (num && !(me && me.id>num)) {
      me = this;
   }
});
```

Now suppose you have id that are "a1", "a2", etc.

Then you can do

```
var me;
$('.a[id^="a"]').each(function(){
   var num = Number(this.id.slice(1));
   if (num && !(me && me.id.slice(1)>num)) {
      me = this;
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! if console.log(me) will get all html, how to get the biggest id value

Comment: see, I told you he wanted the number, not the element ;-)

Comment: @vibskov the highest number is just `me.id`

Comment: if I use if (num && !(me && me.id>num)) {
    me = this;
    console.log(me.id);
   } will get list all number

Answer (score 0):

check this.

```
var highestVal = parseInt($('.a').first().attr('id'));
$('.a').first().siblings().each(function(index, item){
    var crntVal = parseInt($(item).attr('id'));
    if (crntVal > highestVal) { highestVal = crntVal; }
});
alert(highestVal);
```

Comment: please learn when _not_ to use jQuery - `$(item).attr('id') === item.id`